# Syndrome decoding algorithm and standard form

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

Assume I have a linear code over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with dimensions $[3,6]$ and generator matrix $G$ **not in standard form**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&1&1&0 \\
1&0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Suppose I receive the vector $$y = (1,0,1,0,0,1)$$ and I want to correct it using the syndrome decoding algorithm.

- I can put $G$ in standard form by exchanging the first two columns, call it $G'$, get the parity check matrix for the equivalent code, call it $H'$, and then find the original parity check matrix $H$ and apply the *Syndrome decoding algorithm* to the vector $y$, and that is fine.
- **What about if I want to use the SDA algorithm with the parity check matrix $H'$ (the one that corresponds to generator matrix $G'$)?** What should I change?

---

**EDIT**:

In this specific example

$$G' = \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&1&0 \\
0&1&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$H' = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&1&0&0 \\
1&0&1&0&1&0 \\
0&1&1&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

If I want to use  $H'$, I consider $yP=(0,1,1,0,0,1)$. Then $H'\cdot yP=(1,1,1)$.

Therefore, I have to compute the cosets of $(1,1,1)$. It is the set $$\{x \in F_2^6: H' \cdot x = (1,1,1) \}$$

and this is represented by

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+x_4 = 1 \\
x_1+x_3+x_5=1 \\
x_2+x_3+x_6 = 1
\end{cases}
$$

The solutions are given by a $$\text{particular one } + C'  $$ $$ (1,0,1,0,1,0) + C'$$

and doing the computations I choose as coset leader $e_3 + e_4$, obtaining the correction $$c = yP+e_3+e_4 = (0,1,0,1,0,1)$$

**Now**, to obtain the right corrected word, I just multiply by $P^{-1} = P$ (it's orthogonal), and hence I obtain $$cP = (1,0,0,1,01)$$ which is a codeword in $C$ (I just checked it by multiplying: $H\cdot cP = 0$)

Comment: Regarding your example: are you sure your code can correct two errors?  Obviously the yP you picked has more than one error, and I can easily pick out three error messages of weight 2 that yield that syndrome, so decoding wouldn’t be unique...

Comment: Yes, it can correct $2$ errors, as the minimum distance is $2$. My question was just about if it was right the "procedure". it should be okay,right? @rschwieb

Comment: What do you mean "It can correct 2 errors as the minimum distance is 2"?  As far as I can tell, it has minimum distance $3$, meaning it can correct a single error. To correct $2$ errors, you'd need a distance of $5$ or more.

Comment: You know that for binary codes, you can only guarantee correction of $\lfloor \frac d 2\rfloor$ where $d$ is the distance, right?

Comment: my bad, yes you're right (I was doing another exercise and got confused) ! btw, just considering the "algorithm", is it the right way to apply it ? I think so, as $H \cdot cP = 0$ so it's a codeword. @rschwieb

Answer (score 2):

If you used the matrix $P$ to get $GP=G'$, then you would apply the algorithm to the codeword $yP$.

At that point you'd be decoding $yP$ with $H'$ from the code $G'$.  It sounds like you understand how to apply it so... not sure what is left to say.

Comment: So, just to be sure: I apply SDA with $H'$ to the vector $yP=(0,1,1,0,0,1)$ and in the algorithm I will always use the elements of the equivalent code $G'$ (to compute cosets and so on...). Then, I will find the corrected vector $c= y-e$. I don't know now if it's in $C$ or in $C'$... do I have to do $cP$ ? Or is it already in $C$?   @rschwieb

Comment: Your error vector will be in terms of words in the equivalent code. You'd get $c=yP-e$, which would translate to $cP^{-1} = y - eP^{-1}$.  That is, the error in the original code was $eP^{-1}$ and your new corrected word is $cP^{-1}$.

Comment: Try it out: introduc an error on the first position, then on the second position, then on the third position. Things should work out the way you think they should.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try with an example. Just one last question: so, in practice, I do SDA with $yP,H',G'$ and I find the correction $c$, and then I find the **right** correction by doing $cP^{-1}$ @rschwieb

Comment: @bobinthebox yes, that is what I want you to try out a few times to see things work.  I think you’ll see what’s going on  after that.

Comment: I posted your argument with my specific example and did the computations. It seems okay, could you confirm that I did not misunderstood what you wrote? :) @rschwieb